# Cracked Flex Pipe Repair for 2007 Chevy HHR

Tags: exhaust, hhr

Background:

I've been told by my (non-dealer) auto mechanic that I have a crack in the flex pipe that is connected to the exhaust manifold.

Problem:

Said mechanic claims that an after-market kit to repair this problem does not exist for my model year, and it will require a dealer repair costing approximately $1700.

Questions:

1) Is the claim that I have to take this to a dealer accurate?  Is there no after-market part that could be used?

2) Would a custom exhaust shop be able to come up with a "workaround" that would be more affordable?  Would a "normal" mechanic be able to come up with such a repair, or would it require a shop that specialized in exhaust repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is; they are partially correct.

No kit exists to repair the flex. The flex is part of the catalytic converter assembly.

To fix the issue replace the catalytic converter. A retailer such as rockauto sells replacement converters (including the flex) for under $200.